# Combine data from two rows to make one row where that data alternates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

If I have 2 rows of data, A1:E1 and A2:E2, and I want a new row to organize that data by alternating the numbers, A1,A2,B1,B2,C1,C2....

Is there a formula I can use that will copy over and keep the sequence going?

Answer (score 1):

You can fill the following formula across a row to get your alternating data in one row.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$E$2,IF(ISODD(COLUMN()),1,2),INT((COLUMN()+1)/2))
```

Just specify the starting data (both rows) in the first argument of the `INDEX` function. The rest just uses a divisibility trick to make the entries alternate between the two columns.

Example:

[image]